# Align in chemistry

Tags: align, mhchem

Is there any way to align link this?(`+` and `<=>` in the middle)

[image]

I used this code.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kalpurush}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{6}
    &\text{বিক্রিয়াঃ} && \ce{H2} && + && \ce{I2} && \ce{<=>} && 2\ce{HI}\\
    &\text{প্রাথমিক অবস্থাঃ} \qquad && 4.05 && && 4.65 &&  && 0 \\
    &\text{সাম্যবস্থাঃ} && 4.05-\alpha &&  && 4.65-\alpha && && 2\alpha
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

And it gave-

[image]

Comment: If you want to specify the alignment, you probably should use something like `\begin{array}{lccccc}` instead of `alignat`.

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: I edited it and added a compilable code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `array`, instead.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  l
  @{\hspace{3em}}
  c % first column
  @{\:}c@{\:} % plus
  c % second column
  @{\;}c@{\;} % reaction
  c % third column
  @{}
}
\text{Abcdefg} & \ce{H2}     & + & \ce{I2}     & \ce{<=>} & 2\ce{HI}\\
\text{Abcde}   & 4.05        &   & 4.65        &          & 0 \\
\text{Abc}     & 4.05-\alpha &   & 4.65-\alpha &          & 2\alpha
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it with `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand*{\eqmathbox}[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    &\text{Some text} & \eqmathbox[H]{\ce{H2}} & + & \eqmathbox[I]{\ce{I2}} & \ce{<=>} & \eqmathbox[HI]{2\ce{HI}}\\
    &\text{Some longer text} \qquad & \eqmathbox[H]{4.05} & & \eqmathbox[I]{4.65} & & \eqmathbox[HI]{0} \\
    &\text{Text again} & \eqmathbox[H]{4.05-\alpha} & & \eqmathbox[I]{4.65-\alpha} & & \eqmathbox[HI]{2\alpha}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]